# Paypal IPN - Working properly, but it's very easily hackable

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I've been using this script:
http://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/
and I got this to work properly. The thing is - after payment, this transfers to the site:

```
http://www.leagueaccountsbot.xaa.pl/paypal_test/success.php?amt=15.00&cc=USD&item_name=League%20Accounts%20Bot&item_number=1&st=Completed&tx=7VT27047DB709492G
```

And it's enough if you change, for example, the "item_name=XXX" in link - and it will get inserted into the database. Is there anything I can do about it? Shouldn't it be done in IPN.php and just completely removed in success.php?

Comment: *"Shouldn't it be done in IPN.php and just completely removed in success.php?"* - the short answer is yes; build your order in your system before going to PayPal. Rebuild it from your data in `ipn.php` when payment is processed (and update your order/transaction data). The final success page should really just be the "Thank you for your order page" and shouldn't do anything functional.

Comment: I guess I was just being dumb, it was enough to remove the php code from success.php completely and it's working, I think.

Comment: do not perform your database manipulations in success.php. Do them in ipn.php. thats where you can perform secure validation and verify that the payment_id is not a fake.

Comment: i've already solved this issue, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Send request via Curl and save response in server end.

Comment: how does this help OP?